# Python - Appending values to a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

In the code below, each x has 9 values of y. 
I want new_gamesplyed = [x, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9].
But in the list 'difference' all 292 values are getting stored at once.

```
new_gamesplayed = []
difference = []

col_count = df_gamesplayed.shape[1]-1 = 9
l = len(df_gamesplayed) = 292

for x in range(len(df_gamesplayed)):      
    for y in range (1, col_count):
        diff = abs(df_gamesplayed.iloc[x, y] - df_gamesplayed.iloc[x, y + 1])        
        difference.append(diff)
    new_gamesplayed.append([df_gamesplayed.iloc[x, 0], difference])
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide a full (yet minimal) example, with data included, and show where is the output different than what was expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `difference` variable across entire code snippet so it is no wonder that it stores all values that were passed to it by `append`

If i correctly understand you need to "reset" the container between some statements in main loop. So i suggest to reinitialize the bucket collection every time at the main loop statements start. Example:

```
for x in range(len(df_gamesplayed)):      
    d_temp = []  # <---------  reset it here ----------
    for y in range (1, col_count):
        diff = abs(df_gamesplayed.iloc[x, y] - df_gamesplayed.iloc[x, y + 1])        
        d_temp.append(diff)
    new_gamesplayed.append([df_gamesplayed.iloc[x, 0], d_temp])
```